# How can I scroll using the mouse pad while editing a formula in Excel Professional Plus 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I scroll using the mouse pad while editing a formula in Excel Professional Plus 2010 ?

Before I could press F2 and (while in editing mode) I could quickly use 2 fingers on the mouse pad area of my laptop to scroll up/down to see data in another part of my excel sheet and quickly scroll back to my editing cell and finish typing what I was doing.

Now I cannot do that. Is an there any fix to this problem? Actually I have this problem on my new DELL laptop, while my old Acer laptop from a few few years ago it works fine. Both my laptops are sitting next to each other and this feature is working fine only the old one and not the new one. I have no problem scrolling otherwise, but I need to be able to scroll WHILE EDITING a cell, after pressing F2.  It just wont let me scroll in edit mode on my new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the touchpad functionality of your laptop, make sure that your laptop model supports touchpad sliding.

If it doesn't have this feature, you may need to download the driver yourself or use a third-party plug-in.